# how to redirect to homepage after successful login in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to redirect to homepage after `successful login` in ReactJS? and also i want to show `error message` whenever user enter wrong credential. 

i am probably new to ReactJS, it would be great if anybody could help me out what i am trying to solve is. thank you so much in advance and also would be much appreciated.

./src/Login.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Form} from 'antd';


export default class App  extends Component{


  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            username: "",
            password: "",
        }
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onFormSubmit(values){
      console.log(values);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("username", values.username);
      formData.append("password", values.password);

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        };

      try{
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', options).then(() => {
          this.props.history.push('/home')
        });
      }

      catch (error) {
        alert('Login Failed. Try Again')
      }

    };


 render(){
    return(

      <div>
                            <Form onFinish={this.onFormSubmit}>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                    <Form.Item name="username">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
                                    </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                                  <Form.Item name="password">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Password"/>
                                   </Form.Item>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3">
                                        log in
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </Form>

     </div>
```

Comment: Are you using any router? If not, the preferred would be react-router, but reach-router is also an option.

Comment: yes! i am using `react-router`

Comment: You can have state like ‘formSubmitted’ with default value set to false and after fetch is done you can set it to true. In you ‘render()’ method, before returning jsx you can pass an ‘if(this.formSubmitted)’ that would return ‘Redirect’ component from ‘react-router’

Comment: Sorry, I’m typing from my phone, so it’s hard to give a clear example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `react-router` then you should use like this

````
    console.log(values);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", values.username);
    formData.append("password", values.password);

      const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
      };

      fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', options).then((response) => {

        notification.success({
            message: "login successfully."
        });
        this.props.history.push('/your-homepage-route') <---- Navigate after successful login
      }).catch(error => {
        alert('Login Failed. Try Again') <----- Error Handling
      });
  };```
````

Comment: it's showing me `login falied` even i have enter right `username` and `password`

Comment: and it also not redirecting to home page too after successful login.

Comment: @bounty make sure that your component is wrapped using ```withRouter``` from ```react-router-dom```.  Also describe if there are any errors that pop up in the console window for us to better help you.

Comment: please see my question(i have edited). it's not redirecting to `home page` after successfully login. @Michael

Comment: @bounty it would be more helpful if we could see what your routing looks like inside ```index.js```.  I assume that's where all of your routes are being declared?

Comment: do you use any remote application? @Michael

Comment: @Michael okay! you use anydesk or teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214279/discussion-between-bounty-and-michael).

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a new page, this is not dependent on react:

```
window.location = 'http://www.whateveryourpathis.com';
```

Comment: i believe there is a function `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` but i do not know how to use this.

Comment: Also beats the purpose of SPA’s and having a state object.

Comment: using `history.push()` which internally uses `window.history.pushState()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState 

which does not request a totally new document for the route from server(your solution requests server), but instead keeps you on same document and just changes the state of the user's hostory with new state. (Local redirection, handled through script).

Answer (score 0):

I think for redirection, it will be easy if you are using `react-router-dom` package for routing:

1. If you are using it for routing like `<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>`, this supercharge this component which makes it easy to do programmatic redirects with :

   ```
   this.props.history.push('/home')
   ```
2. Otherwise you need to use Height order component from the same package `import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'` then wrap your component with `withRouter(Login)` finally use `this.props.history.push('/home')` for redirection